# Get the complement of an (x,2)-shaped array by deleting rows from an (y,2)-shaped array

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have two arrays, one with a large number of rows and one with a small number of rows, both with 2 columns. I am trying to take the complement of the small array. Such that I delete all rows in the larger array which are also present in the smaller array.

I am currently trying to do this as follows:

```
import numpy as np

my_arr = np.array([[0,1], [1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,5], [3,2]]) # all values
del_arr = np.array([[0,1], [2,3]]) # delete these from all values

complement_arr = np.delete(my_arr, del_arr, axis=0)

In[670]: complement_arr
Out[670]: 
array([[4, 5],
       [3, 2]])
```

As can be seen more rows are deleted than only the ones in `del_arr`, the expected output would be:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 5],
       [3, 2]])
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here and how I can efficiently delete the rows from my `del_arr` array on a larger scale?

Comment: `delete` uses indices, not values

Comment: How do I find the indices of the rows I want to delete?

Answer (score 0):

You could go for a brute force approach by comparing every shape `(2,)` subarray in `del_arr` to every shape `(2,)` subarray in `my_arr`:

```
import numpy as np

my_arr = np.array([[0,1], [1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,5], [3,2]]) # all values
del_arr = np.array([[0,1], [2,3]]) # delete these from all values

eq = my_arr[:, None, :] == del_arr[None, :, :]
mask = eq.all(axis=2).any(axis=1)
# mask is a shape (x,) boolean mask that indicates every row in my_arr
# that also appears in del_arr

complement_arr = my_arr[~mask]
```

complement_arr:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 5],
       [3, 2]])
```

but note that `eq = my_arr[:, None, :] == del_arr[None, :, :]` creates an array of shape `(x, y, 2)`, which could require a lot of memory. There may be more efficient options.